# Why is the spigot on my oil heater dripping?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, heating, heater, oil

We have fuel oil and a Beckett oil burner that heats our house. I just noticed water is dripping out of this hosebib/spigot at the bottom of it:

[image]

**What could be causing this and how can I troubleshoot?** Also, in case you're wondering, we had a basement flood a few months ago and I put down cat litter around the base of my Beckett to wick water away; thats the gravely/grainy stuff you're seeing in the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the spigot, or is there leakage from a corroded boiler?

[*If* you determined it's the valve that's leaking, you'll need to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgzEDZ61bDE):

- Shut the electricity to the heating system to prevent it running while dry.
- Shut the cold-water feed to the boiler.
- Drain the whole heating system through that valve... you could run a garden hose to the fitting once it's cooled.
- Replace the washer in the valve, just like you would a faucet valve.
- Close the repaired valve.
- Open the valve to the cold-water feed *slowly*.
- Check for leaks.
- Once the system is filled at bottom, *purge air from baseboard convectors or radiators.* This is a bit of a nuisance, since each valve at each heater must be opened until air stops hissing, and water starts to drip. Failure to do so will restrict heat to some areas of the house. Purging may need to be repeated after the system runs for a while!
- Turn the electricity on again.
- Turn up the temperature at the room thermostat and check that heat is coming out of all the convectors/radiators.

*Yep, what a pain it is to replace one washer.*

Comment: Thanks for the **awesome** answer @DrMoishe Pippik (+1) -- real quick here, this morning I noticed the water/wetness was gone and all dried up. So this is clearly an intermittent issue that comes and goes. Does that tell you anything else?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix you can get a brass hose cap and screw it on the spigot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jwh20 (+1) -- is there any risk or danger that doing this will block off "pressure" that's correctly trying to be released? You hear stories (possibly urban legends) about water heaters exploding because they were unable to let off pressure. I know this isn't a water heater, but still, the same concerns might be warranted?

Comment: A draincock is not a pressure relief device.  This boiler should have a overpressure relief value that is separate from the drain.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause would be a loose stem package sealing right at the spindle of the dark valve handle - if there is a stem package sealing at all. Just close to that handle is a big nut which needs some tightening (only very few, e.g. 1/8 turn every 5 years) from time to time. Often,  it can be sensed if it is too loose.

If the valve or washer need to be replaced, another simple method to avoid all the work for draining and purging air would be to freeze the line(s) to the valve with CO2 or ice spray. But choosing that method, there is a small possibility that it does not work like intended or the work is not finished when the cooling medium is running out.

Since it is intermittent, another cause could be a defect/de-adjusted pressure compensation tank. Every time the boiler is heating up the water, the pressure raises and needs to be compensated. If that fails, the water takes the weakest point to leave the closed circuit - and may even destroy some components of the heating system.
This is why there should be another item: a safety valve that opens if a certain pressure is reached, e.g. 300kPascal (3 bar). Normally that valve is installed somewhere above the heater. If there is some dirt in that safety valve, it could open too early.